# Looping through a CSV does not add strings with special chars in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have this simple code to store soem data in a MySQL table from a CSV file:

```
$file = "GeoLiteCity-Location.csv";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
    $n++;
    if ($data[0]) {
        $city = str_replace('"', '',$data[3]);
        $region = str_replace('"', '',$data[2]);
        $latitude = $data[5];
        $longitude = $data[6];
        $country_id = $mobbuteo::$db->select('_countries', 'country_id', array('code' => str_replace('"', '',strtoupper($data[1]))));
        $latlong = $mobbuteo::$db->select('_cities', '*', array('latitude' => $latitude, 'longitude' => $longitude));

        if ($country_id[0]['country_id'] !== 0 && $country_id[0]['country_id'] !== '' && $country_id[0]['country_id'] !== NULL)
            if (count($latlong) <= 0)
                $result = $mobbuteo::$db->insert_update('insert', '_cities', array('country_id' => $country_id[0]['country_id'], 'city' => $city, 'region' => $region, 'latitude' => $latitude, 'longitude' => $longitude));

        if (!$result) {
            echo($city);
        }
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));
```

For some reasons in the DB cities with special characters in their names gets cutted off.
For example: `L·i ThiÍu` becomes only `L` in my DB table. I am using `UFT8 General Ci`.

What's the problem there?
But most importantly how do I get now all those cities with special characters and fixing their names correctly?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: How about [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) ?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298353/php-fgetcsv-charset-encoding-problems

Answer (score 0):

Check if your script is running in UTF-8:

```
header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

Check if your database connection is set to UTF-8:

```
->query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Instead of `str_replace` to escape characters, use native database method for that (like `real_escape_string` for `mysqli`). You may wanna check if your `$mobbuteo::$db` has method called `escape` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following statements after opening the connection to your mySQL database

```
@mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"', $conn);
@mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf-8'", $conn);
```