# Can't replace this unicode (�) to " " (space) on csv upload to PHP

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, csv, file-upload

I have a Excel data converted from XLSX to CSV, then I need to upload it to my site. The data shown like this on CSV but changed after upload.

```
// On Excel (CSV)
Row   Description
 1    Enjoy this life without drugs
 2    Life is so short, so enjoy it
```

After uploading to site and inserted to MySQL it's look like this.

```
// On MySQL
Row   Description
 1    Enjoy?this life without?drugs
 2    Life is?so?short, so?enjoy it

// On PHP ( (echo loop).
Row   Description
 1    Enjoy�this life without�drugs
 2    Life is�so�simple, so�enjoy it
```

I was checked on my CSV, it just space that changed into `?` and `�`. So, I'm trying to replace that but all failed using :

```
// $the_string = Line of text Description.
1. str_replace("�", " ", $the_string);
2. str_replace("&#65533", " ", $the_string);
3. str_replace("&#xfffd", " ", $the_string);
4. str_replace("?", " ", $the_string");
```

But, If I'm test it only on `<?php str_replace("�", " ", "a�b"); ?>`, It's working.

I don't know where is the mistake.

This is my source code :

```
public function upload()
{
   $config = array(
      "upload_path" => "./uploads/",
      "allowed_types" => "csv"
   );
   $this->load->library("upload", $config);
   $this->load->helper("file");
   $this->upload->initialize($config);
   $upload = $this->upload->data();
   $file = base_url()."uploads/{$upload['file_name']}";
   $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
   $check_line = 0;
   while ( ! feof($file_handle))
   {
      $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
      $check_line++;
   }
   fclose($file_handle);
   if ($check_line > 1)
   {
      $file_handle2 = fopen($file, "r");
      while ( ! feof($file_handle2))
      {
         $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
         $description = $line_of_text[1];
         $this->model->insert_description($description);
      }
      fclose($file_handle);
   }
}
```

Comment: Think it's encoding problem.
The same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298353/php-fgetcsv-charset-encoding-problems)

Comment: Solved, check for the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
preg_replace('/\x{FFFD}/u', ' ', $the_string);
```

Try it [here](https://eval.in/942421).

**Attention:** This will remove the `�` character from the string, but ONLY if it is the real character stored in the string.

The `�` character may appear in substitution of every character that isn't encoded properly accordingly with the encoding used by, in this case, PHP.

**To remove all non-printable characters use this**:

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $the_string);
```

Try it [here](https://eval.in/942432).

Comment: Hi, I was try your code. The data is gone, only show 1 space on echo. I think it's same like str_replace, only working on `<?php ?>` check

Comment: You must use the `$the_string` variable instead of `$str` of my example. I edited my answer according to your variable's name.

Comment: Sure, I was try that.

Comment: Had you tried now with my last edit (with `$the_string`)?

Comment: I was tried to use `$the_string` and `$line_of_text[1]`. The data is gone, just show `" "` (1 space). I still don't know why.

Comment: That is the same case like : If I'm test it only on `<?php str_replace("�", " ", "a�b"); ?>`, It's working and print `a b`.

Comment: Success ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163938/discussion-between-zinc-and-user2342558).